# Optimizing database design for stack like insert and select pattern?

Tags: database, postgresql, optimization, database-design

I am given a task for which I need to design an efficient table (not limit to sql but I am currently using postgresql) that has the following structure

```
id_table
    latest_update_id
    product_id
    publish_date

product_meta_table
    latest_update_id
    product_id
    meta_related_info1
    meta_related_info2
    ...etc

product_table
    latest_update_id
    product_id
    note_related_info1
    note_related_info2
    ....etc
```

Each `product_id` can have multiple `latest_update_id` since it will get update multiple times per 10min.

Each `product_id` and `latest_update_id` combination will have 1 `product_meta_table` entry and multiple `product_table` entry.

The select pattern is basically the following

```
SELECT *
FROM product_table
WHERE latest_update_id = (SELECT latest_update_id FROM id_table WHERE product_id = 'some_id' ORDER BY publish_date DESC LIMIT 1 )
AND product_id = 'some_id'
```

which is selecting the latest info of a product.

I plan to index `latest_update_id` `product_id` and `publish_date` for all three table.

We are planning to get hit by 10-50k insert per second, and I need to keep historic data because some other team need to do data analysis on it.

Is this a good design? Is there other opportunity for optimizing speed for insert and read?

Am I using completely wrong technology?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: There's a couple of different ways to write that SQL. Some may be more efficient than others. Definitely apply indexes. If another team needs to perform historical analysis, you may wish to consider keeping an 'operational' database with recent transactions only, and a 'historical' database with everything (that is only updated overnight). Depends on whether analysis needs to be up to date.

Comment: A better way to do this is probably to update product_table directly with the latest info, and use a trigger to write the history to a log table. Now you don't need an expensive select to find he latest info every time.

Comment: The sub-query is not needed: `select * from product_table where product_id = '...'  order by publish_date desc limit 1` will be a lot more efficient.